# compile error using malloc outside of main function

Tags: c, malloc

code1

```
#include "header.h"
#define MAX_BUFFER 100
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    node_t* next;
}node_t;
node_t* head = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
....
void insert(node_t** first, int n);
```

code 2

```
#include "header.h"
#define MAX_BUFFER 100
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    node_t* next;
}node_t;
node_t* head = NULL;
void insert(node_t** first, int n);
...
void insert(node_t** first, int n)
{
    node_t* new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
}
```

When I compile code 1, the error occurs and it says

```
llist.c:10:16: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
node_t* head = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

And code2, no error occurred.

I don't get the meaning of compile-time constant. Can anyone please explain me why in code 1 error occurs?

Comment: In C, you can't call functions from outside another function.  In C++, you can use function calls in initializers for variables defined at file scope, but C is _not_ C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course initializing a global variable with a call to a function **requires to execute code to initialize it**, which is not possible at load time, as global variable initializer values are already encoded in the loaded file, as the initialized `.data` section (this is the reason for the initializers to need to be constants)  A call to a function is never a constant expresion, it's return value is a pointer, dependent on the internal state of the `malloc()` library, so it cannot be encoded in the executable file as some fixed value.

But you can initialize it to `NULL`, and then test at some point if its value is `NULL`, then initialize it.  But always after some code has been executed.

Answer (score 2):

At top-level you cannot initialize with `malloc`.

At top-level you need to use only static data, for example,

```
node_t head = { ... };
```

and you fill with static initializers, like `{ some_int, NULL}` or `{ some_int, &other_static_node }`.  Or something like:

```
node_t *head = NULL;
```

and you initialize `head` using `head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` from an initialization function.  Note, I do not cast the output of `malloc`.

Comment: You do it well.  Never cast it. :)  But an explanation of why would be interesting for him, probably, more than the anxiety of knowing that there's something to never do, but not why.  don't you agree?

Comment: It is not "static data". Initializers have to be constant expressions and it is not the same